# Component is not changing on first click in react-router-dom reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

The components does changes but only if clicked more than twice and does not change on first click. If I click to contact us,there will be no change but after 3-4 clicks, it will go to that component

Navbar.jsx code:

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import "./navbar.css";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [showNavItems, setShowNavItems] = useState(false);

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="logo">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="right-nav">
        <ul className={`nav-links ${showNavItems ? "showMenu" : ""}`}>
          <li>
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/home">
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/explore">
              Explore
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/about">
              About
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/contact">
              Contact Us
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div
        className="ham-icon"
        onClick={() =>
          showNavItems ? setShowNavItems(false) : setShowNavItems(true)
        }
      >
        <div className="line"></div>
        <div className="line"></div>
        <div className="line"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

App.jsx code:

```
import "./assets/style/App.css";
import About from "./components/About/About";
import { HeroSection } from "./components/HeroSection/HeroSection";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Contact from "./components/Contact/Contact";
import Explore from "./components/Explore/Explore";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HeroSection />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<HeroSection />} />
          <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route exact path="/explore" element={<Explore />} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can't find what I missed,I am using react-router-dom@6. It works only after few clicks. There is no errors in the console and no warning in the terminal too!

Comment: are you sure that you are clicking the `anchor` tag not the `li` tag?

Comment: Than you very much @Dev-2019 !! It worked..I gave more padding to li instead of anchor..Not it got solved!